# Restore inputs previous session attributes in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to restore the same previous session attributes in tkinter ? for example: having one button to restore the previous session attributes

Is there a way to set inputtxt to the value?

```
def restore():
file1 = open('user.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
unverified_file = Lines[0]
**inputtxt1.set(unverified_file)**
```

AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'set'

Comment: What is _previous session_?

Comment: the gui after closing it

Comment: for exmple: if I typed A ,B ,C in text fields 1,2,3 and closed the GUI. I want to use the same A,B,C in the next time if I click on restore button

Comment: Save the results to a text file. When next time, the restore button is clicked read from that file.

Comment: Can you give an example please? in code

Comment: I updated the question if you can check it please .

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your updated code, you need `insert` not `set`. But first delete the entry -

```
def restore():

    file1 = open('user.txt', 'r')
    Lines = file1.readlines()
    unverified_file = Lines[0]
    inputtxt1.delete(0,'end')
    inputtxt1.insert('end',unverified_file)
```

Also, take a look at this example -

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def save():
    a = entry1.get()
    b = entry2.get()
    
    with open('1.txt','w') as f:
        f.write(a)
        f.write('\n')
        f.write(b)

def restore():
    with open('1.txt','r') as f:
        text = f.read().split('\n')

    entry1.insert('end',text[0])
    entry2.insert('end',text[1])

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(root,text='Save Results',command=save)
button1.pack()

button2 = tk.Button(root,text='Restore Previous Results',command=restore)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```